# Is there any software like 'Primo Cache'?

Tags: software

I've used [PrimoCache](https://www.romexsoftware.com/en-us/primo-cache/) on Windows.
Specifically [Defer Write](https://www.romexsoftware.com/en-us/primo-cache/exsample-improve-write-speed.html) feature not only for performance,

I've used it for drive endurance.

As a switcher from Windows to Mac, I can handle RamDisk thing now, but I can't find alternatives to this software or feature on OS X.

Comment: I'm loathe to ascribe 'snake oil' as a description of it... but I really can't see the point. Samsung's recent white paper on recent SSD technology claims a MTTF of about 300 years.

Comment: What does it do what does use if for  drive endurance. mean?

Comment: @Tetsujin Do you have a link to the white paper?  Sounds like fun reading.

Comment: @jmh - tbh, it's too far back in my browser history to come up with the link I was thinking of 2½ years ago - but this is their current warranty on drives, which quite impressed me even today - 10 years, 600TBW or 5 years, 4,800 TBW for the high-end stuff. That's "send it back for free if it breaks" support, let alone 'mean time to failure'. https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/support/warranty/

Comment: Yea pretty impressive.  Thanks anyway. I'll see if google can find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple's [Fusion Drive technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_Drive) encompasses some of what PrimoCache does, in addition to the [design of the filesystem](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Apple-claim-defragmentation-in-OS-X-is-unnecessary) itself. Tetsujin's comment is right on. Apple's disk interface is well thought out, robustly designed, and doesn't need any external 'aids' to caching disks for performance sake.

Comment: Also, OS X natively caches files in RAM from disk, eventually using all available memory to do so.

Answer (score 2):

PrimoCache is a more advanced solution. It can't be compared with Apple's very limited "Fusion Drive" technology. PrimoCache provides automatic L1 (RAM) and L2 (SSD) caching and doesn't "shuffle" blocks like Fusion Drive. Also, it is multi-device, you can use it with a large JBOD or RAID setup. This isn't about robustness, Windows also has built-in caching in various forms, similar to macOS' ones.

I'm also looking for some kind of solution like PrimoCache for macOS operating system. Fusion Drive is similar, but I need the extended functionality.